# Change the color of the letter

Tags: c++, colors

How I can change the color of the letter in C++, I found that I could change the whole text color via

```
system("color 01")
```

but it changes all the text, how I can change the color of one letter/word?

Comment: C++ knows nothing about color. You will have to use some external library that may be operating-system specific (like curses)

Comment: and how I can do it via Window.h??

Comment: @Mandruk - here is the help if you want to do it using Windows and the supplied header/dll/library files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx Using a library like curses or ncurses will certainly be easier - but at the expense of not gaining the experience of doing it 'yourself', or at least as close to yourself as a protected-mode operating system will allow - we used to just write bytes to the memory at 0xA000 or 0xB800 in the days of DOS.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
#include<windows.h>
HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    cout << "TIC TAC TOE GAME";
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
```

Comment: Now that we know you are using Windows and wish to set the colour of text in a console window, please add those details to your question.